# set required field foreach loop

Tags: magento-1.9

How to set required field

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('modulename/index/controlleraction') ?>" id="requestfish">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php //echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="true" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="true"/>
    <input type="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required="true"/>
      <?php $addfish = Mage::getStoreConfig('mps_requestfish/enable/addfish');
        $array =  explode(',', $addfish);
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            echo "<div class='list-content'><input class='the-terms' type='checkbox' class='checkbox required-entry' value='$item'><b>$item</b></input></div>";
        }?>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="enter" />

</form>
```

it add required for all Checkbox. In that if one checkbox i miss it show's error how to over come this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `required-entry` class to the `input`. Then the Magento validation javascript will prevent the form posting without the field.

Also, you are missing a `name` attribute, so you will not be able to process the response in the form post (although with a required-entry, the answer could only be "yes").

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Is that checkbox inside a form? Magento Validation requires the form to be defined and a form JS created (such as `var dataForm = new VarienForm('review-form');` in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml`)

Comment: it's inside form only

Comment: And that form has `new VarienForm('something')` defined? Also... the validation will only work if the user is submitting the form... they are clicking anywhere else (or a different form) then the checkbox is not going to function as expected... and you might be required to write custom JS to handle the desired behavior.

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: Add a JS line after the form `<script type="text/javascript">var requestfish Form = new VarienForm('requestfish');</script>

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: And are there any console errors or anything? Something else is going on, and you haven't provided enough information.